# Yii2 how can I add code snippet in CKEditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor, yii2

I have downloaded CKEditor from here https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget
Now I would like to integrate code snippet http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_codesnippet

Mayby someone could explain how to do this step by step? After I downloaded ckeditor via composer, I added

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'instruction')->textarea()
->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'full'
    ]);
```

How can I integrate code snippet now?

Comment: Have you installed it through composer?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it doesn't have code snippet in it, it should be installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Composer packages are installed in `vendor` directory in root dir of your app. I bet that it will be something like `vendor/dosamigos/ckeditor`. You should find there plugins folder where you can install code snippet accordingly to CKEditor documentation. Then when you use it in Yii2 code write something similar to:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'field_name')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 10],
    'preset' => 'full', 
    'clientOptions' => ['extraPlugins' => 'codesnippet']
]) ?>
```

Comment: And before that,I have to use CKeditor Builder, then download their archive with ckeditor and code snippet, replace CKEditor downloaded via composer to CKEDitor downloaded from CKeditor builder? Is it right? If I run composer update code snippet will be broken that way?

Comment: Well I didn't think about CKEditor Builder but it might work that way. You should replace only javascript code form this widget and update form composer shouldn't broke anything (since this files are not part of package)

Comment: I have replaced ckeditor.js, config.js,build-config.js, placed folder named "codesnippet" to folder plugins. 'clientOptions' => ['extraPlugins' => 'codesnippet'] has broken editor, so I wrote 'clientOptions' => ['config.extraPlugins' => 'codeSnippet'], it has not broken it, but code snippet didn't appear. I guess I don't realy understand documentation, since they didn't write where I should do changes, so it could work or I couldn't find the explanation..

Comment: `'clientOptions' => ['config.extraPlugins' => 'codeSnippet']` might be a good call but remember that `codeSnippet` part must be exactly the same as plugin folder name so it should be `'clientOptions' => ['config.extraPlugins' => 'codesnippet']`

Comment: Unfortunately, 'clientOptions' => ['config.extraPlugins' => 'codesnippet'] isn't working too.. I think I have done something wrong when I installed it. I just placed codesnippet in plugins and changed some js files.

Comment: try to revert CKEditor js files and just copy code snippet to plugins folder and then specify `clientOptions`. I hope it'll work because I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Someone just used ckeditor builder and replaced whole folder named "ckeditor" in vendor and it worked. When I am doing so, it makes no changes at all. But thank you for your advices)

Answer (score -2):

You just add this one code on your form file:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'field_name')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 10],
        'preset' => 'full', 
    ]) ?>
```